# Elasticsearch SELECT * FROM IP="1.1.1.1" AND NAME="ETH1/10"

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

I am ne on `elastichSearch`. i am trying the exact match and and operation. I tried so many ways but all the time the response is mess for me. It is like fuzzy match. I need exact match as `RDBMS`

```
SELECT * FROM IP="1.1.1.1" AND NAME="ETH1/10"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u share your mapping, sample docs and expected result, so that we can provide working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You need the exact match than instead of `match` query use [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html)

**Adding a working example**

**Index mapping**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "ip" :{
                "type" : "ip"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index sample doc**

```
{
    "name" : "ETH1/10",
    "ip" : "1.1.1.1"
}
```

**And search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [ --> use `filter` as pointed by @Val in the comment.
                {
                    "term": {
                        "ip": "1.1.1.1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": { --> `term` query for exact match.
                        "name": "ETH1/10"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**And search result**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "65167713",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "ETH1/10",
                    "ip": "1.1.1.1"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Use `filter` instead of `must`, no need for ranking, just a simple yes/no matching (+ ability to cache filters)

Comment: @Val yes, you are correct, edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
{
   "query":{
        "bool":{
            "must":[
                {
                    "match":{
                        "IP":"1.1.1.1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match":{
                        "NAME":"ETH1/10"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
      }
   }
}
```